# fix the offset on other client's char when re-entering FOV, (PyGame and sockets)

Tags: python, sockets, pygame, logic

i hope there is no harm with posting a question here. it really drives me mad...

https://hastebin.com/ekigenewel.rb <- client

https://hastebin.com/esuhanigop.py <- server

https://hastebin.com/orutodejif.yaml <- .owo map file

I do get that bug tracing takes time and will to help, hence im not expecting anything, just i doubt i can do it myself, i already wasted like 4 hours on it
The idea is im making a multiplayer with pygame and sockets. I have an issue which occurs when char A on client A exits out of client B FOV and second follows it afterwards. The thing is to client B char A is offset with constant delta [3.3].

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question needs to include the relevant code-section,  and have a clear description of the problem - what is happening, and what was expected to happen.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your network code does not handle the client disconnecting.  An easy way to detect this is when the socket `.recv()` returns an empty list of data.  Currently it goes into a fast *infinite* loop.

A small patch to your `esuhanigop.py` `threaded_client()` function is enough to fix the issue:

```
def threaded_client(connection,addr):
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(2048)
        if ( len( data ) == 0 ):                     # Client has disconnected
            break                                    # Stop communications
        set_dat(addr,str(data,encoding='UTF-8'))
        dat = get_dat()
        if dat:
            connection.sendall(str.encode(dat,encoding='UTF-8'))
    connection.close()
```

With this patch I am able to multiply connect and disconnect from the server without seeing any python errors.